# Typeahead minlengh 0 suggestion not showing bloodhound

Tags: javascript, jquery, autosuggest, typeahead.js, typeahead

I am working on autosuggestion task and i have requirement like if typeahead suggestion textbox is empty shows default options on suggestion list like below jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5xxYq/

This example working perfectly. but I  have retrieved a suggestion list from remote using bloodhound is not working listed below my piece of code:

```
var sos_adapt = new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
                        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.value);
                    },
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    remote: {
                        url: 'appsearch?ty=so&cid=%CID&query=%QUERY',
                        replace: function(url, query) {
                            return url.replace('%QUERY', query).replace('%CID', customer_id);
                        },
                        filter: function(sos) {

                            return $.map(sos, function(sos) {
                                return {
                                    so_desc: sos.so_desc,
                                    so_no: sos.so_no,
                                    so_details: sos.so_no + " : " + sos.so_desc,
                                    customer_id: sos.customer_id,
                                    customer_details: sos.customer_id + " : " + sos.customer_name
                                };
                            });
                        },
                        ajax: {
                            global: false,
                            beforeSend: function(xhr)
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                //initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
                sos_adapt.initialize();

                $('#so_details').typeahead(null, {
                    displayKey: 'so_no',
                    source: sos_adapt.ttAdapter(),
                    minLength: 0,
                    templates: {
                        empty: [
                            '<div class="sug_items">',
                            'unable to find any so#!',
                            '</div>'
                        ].join('\n'),
                        suggestion: Handlebars.compile([
                            '<div class="sug_items"><p class="repo-language">SO# : {{so_no}}</p>',
                            '<p class="repo-name">{{so_desc}}</p></div>'
                        ].join(''))
                    }
                });
```

my code was working perfect when user type text on textbox. but, when user focus empty textbox bloodhound not sending remote request for suggestion. but, i tried code for on focus  show suggestion list on typeahead textbox below:

```
$("#so_details").on("click", function() {
                    var ev = $.Event("keydown");
                    ev.keyCode = ev.which = 40;
                    $(this).trigger(ev);
                    return true;
 });
```

this code pick from above jsfiddle example, can any one guide me how to do that? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, what results can it return? You are using a remote query to populate the results. On default focus either provide an array of suggestion or use `prefetch` method

Comment: @Edward thanks for your response, i want to bloodhound integration, not a prefetch method. my problem is not calling remote url request when textbox is empty on focus. but, it's calling when user type a text on textbox did you understand what's my problem?

Comment: I found an answer to a similar question. Try this link.

[Show full list of suggestions on click with typeahead and bloodhound][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27145346/4799064